# How to combine together the characters of two strings in C?

Tags: c, string

Given this homework: Write a function which has 3 parameters: The first two will be combined in the 3rd. Example: s1=”abcde”, s2=”1234567”, and the result:  s3=”a1b2c3d4e567”.

Thank you for your answers in advance. :)

My code looks like this so far(and the problem is it only works when the length of the the two strings are equal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int homework(char a[], char b[])
{
    char c[210]={'0'};
    int h1=strlen(a);
    int h2=strlen(b);
    int i=0;
    int j;
    int db=0;
    int l=0;
    while ( h1>=0 && h2>=0 )
    {
        db++;
        c[i]=a[l];
        c[i+1]=b[l];

        h2--;
        h1--;
        i+=2;
        l++;
    }
    h1++;
    h2++;

    printf("%d %d",h1,h2);

    if (h1>0){
        i--;
        while (h1>0)
        {
            c[i]=a[l];
            l++;
            i++;
            h1--;
        }
    }

    if (h2>0){
        i--;
        while (h2>0)
        {
            c[i]=a[l];
            l++;
            i++;
            h2--;
        }
    }

    for (j=0; j<strlen(a)+strlen(b); j++)
        printf("%c",c[j]);
}


int main()
{
    char a[100],b[100];

    gets(a);
    gets(b);
    homework(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Test if you have reached the end of the string, and only increment and print if you are *not* at the end of the string.

Comment: the function which has 3 parameters.

Comment: Please describe "randomly" in detail.

Comment: See the example please. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @Dora It seems that it is not random. It is simply alternating.

Comment: Oh, yes, yes. The homework says the 3rd should combine the characters as char from the 1st string should be followed by a char from the 2nd string, and then char from the 1st again, then 2nd and so on.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/uZzX7T)

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void combinestrings(char* str1,char* str2,char* outputstr)
{
    int slen1 = (int)strlen(str1);
    int slen2 = (int)strlen(str2);
    int slength;
    if (slen1 < slen2)
        slength = (int)strlen(str2);
    else
        slength = (int)strlen(str1);

    int charptr = 0;
    for (int n=0;n < slength;n++)
    {
        if (*(str1+n) && slen1)
        {
            *(outputstr+charptr) = *(str1+n);
            ++charptr;
            --slen1;
        }
        if (*(str2+n) && slen2)
        {
            *(outputstr+charptr) = *(str2+n);
            ++charptr;
            --slen2;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    char* str1 = "abcde";
    char* str2 = "123456789";
    char out[256];

    combinestrings(str1, str2, &out[0]);

    printf("%s\n",out);
}
```

Seems to compile okay under Linux gcc.

Or (as Roi points out) if you don't mind memory allocation of the output string.  Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void combinestrings(char* str1,char* str2,char* outputstr)
{
    int slen1 = (int)strlen(str1);
    int slen2 = (int)strlen(str2);
    int slength;
    if (slen1 < slen2)
        slength = (int)strlen(str2);
    else
        slength = (int)strlen(str1);

    int charptr = 0;
    for (int n=0;n < slength;n++)
    {
        if (*(str1+n) && slen1)
        {
            *(outputstr+charptr) = *(str1+n);
            ++charptr;
            --slen1;
        }
        if (*(str2+n) && slen2)
        {
            *(outputstr+charptr) = *(str2+n);
            ++charptr;
            --slen2;
        }
    }
}

void main()
{
    char* str1 = "abcde";
    char* str2 = "123456789";
    char* outstr;

    //Preallocate our output string and set memory to zero
    int slen1 = (int)strlen(str1);
    int slen2 = (int)strlen(str2);
    outstr = (char*)calloc((slen1+slen2)+1,sizeof(char));
    if (!outstr)
    {
        printf("Could not allocate output string\n");
        return;
    }

    //Call our strings 'riffle' function
    combinestrings(str1, str2, &outstr[0]);

    //Output string
    printf("%s\n",outstr);

    //Deallocate our memory
    free(outstr);
}
```

Comment: There is a buffer overflow vulnerability in your code. The size of the combined string might be longer than 256

Comment: Added memory allocation of resulting string

Answer (score 0):

This workse fine. Make following changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int homework(char a[], char b[])
{
    char c[210]={'0'};
    int h1=strlen(a);
    int h2=strlen(b);
    int i=0;
    int j;
    int db=0;
    int l=0;
    while ( h1>=0 && h2>=0 )
    {
        db++;
        c[i]=a[l];
        c[i+1]=b[l];

        h2--;
        h1--;
        i+=2;
        l++;
    }
    h1++;
    h2++;

    printf("%d %d",h1,h2);

    if (h1>0){
      // i--; //No need to decrement

        while (h1>0)
        {
            c[i]=a[l];
            l++;
            i++;
            h1--;
        }
    }

    if (h2>0){
       // i--; //No need to decrement

        while (h2>0)
        {
            c[i]=b[l]; //here it should be 'b' not 'a'
            l++;
            i++;
            h2--;
        }
    }

    for (j=0; j<=strlen(a)+strlen(b); j++) //use '<=' not '<'
        printf("%c",c[j]);
    printf("\n");
}


int main()
{
    char a[100],b[100];

    gets(a);
    gets(b);
    homework(a,b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code.

The minor issues:

1. You defined your `homework` function as `int homework(char a[], char b[])` - but there is no `return` statement in that function.
2. What is the usage of the variable `db` in the function `homework`? I don't think I understood its usage - was declaring (or using) that variable really necessary?

Now the major issues:

This time, at first I am focusing on this loop -

```
while( h1>=0 && h2>=0 )
{
    // your code
}
```

To show what mistake you have done - let's assume two strings `a="abc"` (`strlen(a)=3`) and `b="12345"` (`strlen(b)=5`).

Your loop will work correctly till `l=2` - at that point (`l=2`), the output `char` array `c={'a','1','b','2','c','3'}`.

But after that, because then `h1=0` and `h2>0`, you will take one additional `char` from `a` and `b` for the output array - which are at that moment `'\0'` and `'4'` respectively. After this iteration, the output array becomes `{'a','1','b','2','c','3','\0','4'}`. You should not be doing this iteration of the loop.

Considering this issue, your loop should become like this:

```
while( h1>0 && h2>0 )
{
    // your code
}
```

Or, maybe like this:

```
while( a[l]!='\0' && b[l]!='\0' )
{
    // your code
}
```

After this loop, I see another loop like this:

```
while (h2>0)
{
    c[i]=a[l]; // ------ (!)
    l++;
    i++;
    h2--;
}
```

Because initially `h2=strlen(b);`, at that moment `h2` represents the number of `char` remaining to be copied to `c` from `b`. But in this loop, you tried to copy `char` from `a`.

So, according to my understanding, the `(!)` line should be -

```
c[i]=b[l];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* combine.c

*/

#include <stdio.h>

void combine(const char str1[], const char str2[], char str3[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    // combine alternating characters of str1 and str2 up to
    // the end of one of the strings 
    while ((str1[i] != '\0') && (str2[i] != '\0')) {
        str3[index++] = str1[i];
        str3[index++] = str2[i];
        ++i;
    }

    if (str1[i] != '\0') {
        // str1 has additional characters
        while (str1[i] != '\0') {
            str3[index++] = str1[i++];
        }
    }
    else {
        // str2 may have additional characters
        while (str2[i] != '\0') {
            str3[index++] = str2[i++];
        }
    }

    // terminate the string with a null character
    str3[index] = '\0';    
}

int main(void)
{
    const char s1[] = { "abcde" };
    const char s2[] = { "1234567" };
    char s3[128];

    combine(s1, s2, s3);
    printf("\n"
          "%s combined with %s = %s\n", s1, s2, s3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
'

```
void    Homework(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  int   k;
  char *str3;

  i = 0;
  j = 0;
  k = 0;
  str3 = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(str1) + strlen(str2)) + 1);
  while (strlen(str3) != strlen(str1) + strlen(str2))
    {
      if (k % 2 == 0 && str1[i] != 0)
        {
          str3[k] = str1[i];
          i++;
        }
      else if (k % 2 == 1 && str2[j] != 0)
        {
          str3[k] = str2[j];
          j++;
        }
      else if ((i + 1) > strlen(str1))
        {
          str3[k] = str2[j];
          j++;
        }
      else if ((j + 1) > strlen(str2))
        {
          str3[k] = str1[i];
          i++;
        }
      k++;
    }
  printf("Your combine string is: %s. \n", str3);
}'
```

PS: Don't forget to return something when you create an int function ;)